# Data filtering in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to do a certain kind of filtering using Spark. I have a data frame that looks like the following:

```
ID   Property#1   Property#2   Property#3
-----------------------------------------
01   a            b            c
01   a            X            c
02   d            e            f
03   i            j            k
03   i            j            k
```

I expect the properties for a given ID to be the same. In the example above, I would like to filter out the following:

```
ID   Property#2
---------------
01   b
01   X
```

Note that it is okay for IDs to be repeated in the data frame as long as the properties are the same (e.g. ID '03' in the first table). The code needs to be as efficient as possible as I am planning to apply it on datasets with >10k rows. I tried extracting the distinct rows using the `distinct` function in DataFrame API, grouped them on the ID column using `groupBy` and aggregated the results using `countDistinct` function, but unfortunately I couldn't get a working version of the code. Also the way I implemented it seems to be quite slow. I was wondering if anyone can provide some pointers as to how to approach this problem.

Thanks!

Comment: Seems that you need to `groupBy` by `id` first, then `filter` by `value.size > 1`, then `flatMap` values to original ungrouped format.

Comment: `groupBy` returns an object of type `GroupedData`. I don't think you can apply `filter` on `GroupedData` unless I am missing something?

Comment: Also it seems most of the time spent in my code is in `groupBy` (even though I apply it on the DataFrame and not the underlying RDD). Is there any way to avoid the grouping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can for example aggregate and join. First you'll have to create a lookup table:

```
val df = Seq(
  ("01", "a", "b", "c"), ("01", "a", "X", "c"),
  ("02", "d", "e", "f"), ("03", "i", "j", "k"),
  ("03", "i", "j", "k")
).toDF("id", "p1", "p2", "p3")

val lookup = df.distinct.groupBy($"id").count
```

Then filter the records:

```
 df.join(broadcast(lookup), Seq("id"))

 df.join(broadcast(lookup), Seq("id")).where($"count" !== 1).show
 // +---+---+---+---+-----+
 // | id| p1| p2| p3|count|
 // +---+---+---+---+-----+
 // | 01|  a|  b|  c|    2|
 // | 01|  a|  X|  c|    2|
 // +---+---+---+---+-----+
```